# How to display title in windows 7 jumplist

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I'm writing a .net (3.0) program using Visual C++,
when running the program on the Windows 7 jump list it only displays "XXX.exe" I want it to display the name of my application, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the IPropertyStore interface. This [CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/SevenGoodiesJumpListTasks.aspx#settingup) demonstrates creating and setting a Jump List (with its title).

```
CComQIPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropStore = pLink;
PROPVARIANT pv;

  InitPropVariantFromString ( L"Red Text", &pv );

  // Set the title property.
  pPropStore->SetValue ( PKEY_Title, pv );
  PropVariantClear ( &pv );

  // Save the changes we made to the property store
  pPropStore->Commit();
```